# showing a set has measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a measureable set with $m(A) < \infty$. For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we define:
$$A_x = A\cap \{x+n|n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$

I am trying to show that the set: $$B=\{x\in\mathbb{R} : |A_x| = \infty\}$$
has measure $0$. That is, for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $A_x$ is finite.

Hints will be appreciated!

Comment: $m(A)<0$? So $m$ is not the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @AnneBauval fixed it, thanks

Comment: If $A=\mathbb R$, your conjecture fails.

Comment: Maybe we are assuming $m(A)<\infty$?

Comment: @Arthur you’re right

Comment: @ChrisSanders no. A set with measure zero can still contain an infinite amount of points…

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $B$ had positive measure.

Then $B\bigcap A$ would have positive measure. (It couldn't be null. If it were null, then $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}n+(B\bigcap A)$ would also be null. But this union is equal to $B$.)

There would then exist $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $S=B\bigcap A\bigcap[n,n+1]$ had positive measure.

Without loss of generality, let $n=0$. In other words, $S=B\bigcap A\bigcap [0,1]$ had positive measure.

For each $x\in S$, there are infinitely many $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x+m\in A$.

Here's how you'd show that $A$ had infinite measure. Imagine that $S$ were a hole in the ground, and you were trying to fill up the hole with elements of $A$ outside $S$. For each $x\in S$, you find a single integer-translate of $x$, which we can call $x'$. You put all the $x'$ in the hole $S$, and you'll have filled up the hole. But because of the properties of $B$, each $x$ has infinitely many other integer-translates. Therefore, find your choices of $x''$, which you can choose to avoid intersecting with any of the $x'$. You can re-fill the hole as many times as you want. This means that $A$ would have infinite measure.

Formally, here's how to construct $S'$. Look within $[1,2]$ for all integer- translates of all elements of $S$. Then, look within $[-1,0]$ for all integer-translates of every $x\in S$ such that a translate hasn't already been found for $x$. Then, repeat for $[2,3]$. Then for $[-2,-1]$. Etc. The resulting set $S'$ will have measure exactly equal to $S$.

I'll let you figure out how to construct $S''$ and so on.

Comment: I don’t really understand your first transition and the argument about $S$ and $S^\prime$, why they have the same measure?